# WPF Statusbar, stretch textblock to take as much space as possible

Tags: wpf, xaml, statusbar

I created my own simple statusbarcontrol with 3 TextBlocks. Now I would like that the first Textblock takes as much space as it has available. That I don't seem to get done.. Now it only takes the space needed to display the text.

XAML:

```
  <StatusBar Background="{StaticResource GradientBrush}">
<StatusBar.ItemsPanel>
  <ItemsPanelTemplate>
    <Grid>
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    </Grid>
  </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</StatusBar.ItemsPanel>
<StatusBarItem HorizontalAlignment="Left"
               HorizontalContentAlignment="Right">
  <Border BorderThickness="1"
          BorderBrush="Black"
          Padding="5 0 5 0"
          Background="White">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Message, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
             Foreground="{Binding TextColorMessage}"
             Background="White"
             />
  </Border>
</StatusBarItem>
<Separator Grid.Column="1" />
<StatusBarItem Grid.Column="2"
               HorizontalAlignment="Right">
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DatabaseName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
</StatusBarItem>
<Separator Grid.Column="3" />
<StatusBarItem Grid.Column="4"
               HorizontalAlignment="Right">
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ComputerName}" />
</StatusBarItem>
```

[image: My StatusBar]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You had set the `StatusBarItem` `HorizontalAlignment="Left"` when it should be `Stretch`, same for the `HorizontalContentAlignment`.
Also would suggest setting `Margin="0"` on the border.

This is what I did so it will work for me:

```
<StatusBarItem HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
               HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    <Border BorderThickness="1"
            BorderBrush="Black"
            Margin="0"
            Padding="5 0 5 0"
            Background="White">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Message, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                   Foreground="{Binding TextColorMessage}"
                   Background="White"/>
    </Border>
</StatusBarItem>
```

Comment: "if this is helpful please mark as answer", no need to tell that. OP already knows.

Comment: THx, so simple again :) I've marked this as the answer because of the code example. Florian's solution is also good.

Answer (score 6):

Try setting the StatusBarItem's `HorizontalAlignment` and `HorizontalContentAlignment` to `Stretch`.

Answer (score 0):

Set the StatusBarItem's HorizontalContentAlignment to Stretch and the TextBlock's TextAlignment property to Right. (This second setting is only needed for the first StatusBarItem as it seems that you try to align the text to the right in it.)

Answer (score 0):

StatusBar has only one HorizontalAlignment=Right item to effect, so you can get only the last item in wanted place. You can set statusBar's FlowDirection="RightToLeft" and add item in reversed order. Details: right placed items needn't StatusBarItem surrounded, but the left one need to be streched. Following code:

```
<StatusBar VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FlowDirection="RightToLeft"><!--flow right to left cause items right aligned-->
    <!--make item's flow back left to right, avoid display disorder-->
    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock_status_R1" Text="111.147.168.20" Grid.Column="2" Margin="10,0" FlowDirection="LeftToRight"/>
    <Separator/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock_status_R2" Text="Working" Margin="10,0" FlowDirection="LeftToRight"/>
    <Separator/>
    <!--To fill rest space，need StatusBarItem packing and default HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"-->
    <StatusBarItem FlowDirection="LeftToRight">
        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock_status_L1" Text="Information here."/>
    </StatusBarItem>
</StatusBar>
```